# Better way to Vlookup

Tags: excel, python-3.x, vba, dataframe, vlookup

I would like to know if there is a better alternative to Vlookup to find matches between two cells (or Python Dfs).

Say I have the below Dfs,[image]

I want my code to check if the values in DF1 was in DF2, If values  **exactly match OR if the values partially matche** return me the value in the DF2.

Just like the matches in 4th column Row 2,3 returned values.

*Thanks Amigo!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as you probably suspected already, you have several options.  You can easily search for an exact match, like this.

```
=VLOOKUP(value,data,column,FALSE)
```

Here is an example.

https://www.excelfunctions.net/vlookup-example-exact-match.html

Or, consider doing a partial match, as such.

```
=VLOOKUP(value&"*",data,column,FALSE)
```

Here is an example.

https://exceljet.net/formula/partial-match-with-vlookup

Oh, you can do a fuzzy match as well.  Use the AddIn below for this kind of task.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011

In Python, it would be done like this.

```
matches = []
for c in checklist:
  if c in words:
    matches.append(c)
```

Obviously, the items in the square brackets are the items in the list.

For Python fuzzy matches, follow the steps outlined in the link below.

https://marcobonzanini.com/2015/02/25/fuzzy-string-matching-in-python/